# Yarn install error. "getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND bnpm.byted.org"."

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg

when I run `yarn install`, there are many info
`"There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying..."` to me, and an error:
An unexpected error occurred:

```
"http://bnpm.byted.org/follow-redirects/-/follow-redirects-1.14.9.tgz: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND bnpm.byted.org".
```

I have changed the mirror source, but it don't work.